# Two Inputs to Output in Excel - Nested If?

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, vlookup

I am trying to compare one cell input against another spreadsheet to see if there is a match.
If yes, then I want to compare a keyword phrase to output data associated with that keyword.

```
Name    Random
A       Doesn't Matter
B       Oesn't Atter
C       Esn't tter


Name    New Key Match   Total
A         US             100
B         ES             200
C         PD             300
D         JD             400
E         MD             500
```

So if I'm trying to match A to A, then "US" to US to print 100...I've tried something like this

```
if(column1=arrayName, vlookup('US',secondspreadsheet!B:C,2,false),"#NA)
```

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to do execute this correctly?

Comment: Is it always 'US' that you are looking up as a second condition? I'm not quite understanding the question.

Comment: Yes it's a word I'm trying to match as the second condition, not a cell match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sumifs for this:

```
=sumifs(secondspreadsheet!C:C, secondspreadsheet!B:B, "US", secondspreadsheet!A:A, A2)
```

Assumed here that A2 was the firstspreadsheet's value where "A" is.